# how to find or know the values for Z-axis in octomap?

Tags: navigation, octomap, octomap-mapping, amcl, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an octomap and trying to do localization with it. I trying to make a slice from a 3d-map (octomap) to consider a single 2d plane for localization with amcl package. I uploaded the map in rviz using octomap_server_node,

$ rosrun octomap_server octomap_server_node bin.bt _occupacy_min_z:=-0.01 _occupancy_max_z:=0.01

I tried different z values in different maps, though I cannot find how the z-values are distributed in the z-axis. I would like to find where the zero of the z-axis lies and I believe that z-values are in meter.

Bottom line is how to slice the 3d map to get a single 2d plane.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

---

Updated:

The resolution=0.025, so i started bigger values. I use rviz to visualize the map, after using the above command. Either I use values in negative z-plane  (ex. {-0.05,0} or positive z-plane {0,0.05}, always the map lies in negative plane of the z-axis (which is viewed in 'rviz'). Also, it seems to be more thicker in z-axis for thickness 0.05m.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43756/how-to-find-or-know-the-values-for-z-axis-in-octomap?/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Zero lies in z=0.0m in your global map frame, however you arrange that with tf. That depends on where and how you built your map. Of course all units are meters as it is the standard in ROS.

When you slice with occupancy_min/max_z, make sure that the interval is large enough to hold one voxel, i.e., larger than the octree file resolution.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-09-14**:
i cannot type bigger sentences here. So, please refer the updated part in the question.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-09-14**:
Sorry, but I don't see a real question in the update, or understand what you're trying to achieve...

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-09-14**:
I am trying to take single plane out of the 3d octomap. So, I try to access the values in z-axis of the octomap. But, when I try to acheive it via 'occupancy_min/max_z' parameters, I face the problem described in the updated part. So, I would like know how to access those values. ex. z{0,0.05}.